# Can I render a view into an outlet in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to display a modal dialog in my application and want to be able to programmatically render it to the page. My root template looks like this

```
{{outlet}}
{{outlet "modal"}}
```

Then when a user presses a button, a controller action is fired and I want to be able to call something like

```
App.Modal.create().appendTo("modal");
```

Obviously that won't work since appendTo takes a jquery selector but does anyone know of a better way to do this?

### Edit:

I could also just use the appendTo method but everytime I do I get a deprecated warning cannot append to default container.  I was using a ContainerView and appending that and then updating the container view but nothing worked.

Comment: have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17396994/modal-popup-with-ember-1-0-rc6, it may help you

Answer (score 2):

Instead of handling button press via a controller action, let it bubble up to the router. Since your outlet is defined in `application.hbs` it makes sense to handle the event in `ApplicationRoute`. Something like:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  events: {
    openModal: function() {
      this.render('modal', { into: 'application', outlet: 'modal' });
    }
  }
});
```

This will render your modal view/template into the `modal` outlet of the `application` template.

Comment: can you render `into` from anywhere other than the router? I'm thinking of a tab-style navigation. It'd be nice if the container view could render the children.