# How can I reuse modal template in ember for multiple popups?

Tags: ember.js, popup, modal-dialog

I found this very useful [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17396994/modal-popup-with-ember-1-0-rc6) where it shows how to create a modal template. This is the [code](http://jsbin.com/onuHEMA/1/edit) they are referring to in that question.

I would like to extend this program and have two modal popups created with different content displayed. However, I am not sure how to do this.

I tried to use boolean variable value to determine which data to display in the modal popup but it doesn't work. Here is what I have tried out. I have shown the relevant parts below and the full working program can be found [here](http://jsbin.com/oYEFiTi/5/).

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

  isFirst : false,

  events: {
     open: function() {
           isFirst = true;
           this.render('modal', { into: 'application', outlet: 'modal' });
     },

     openModal: function() {
           isFirst = false;
          this.render('modal', { into: 'application',     outlet: 'modal' });
     },
});
```

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" {{action close target="view"}}>&times;</button>

  {{#if isFirst}}
  <h3>Modal header</h3>
  {{else}}
    My Header
  {{/if}}

</div>
```

Both popups show "My Header" as the header which means the variable isFirst does not get set.

Any idea how to approach this problem? Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both popups show "My Header" because the template is referencing an `isFirst` property of `ApplicationController`. To set that property from events in ApplicationRoute, try the following:

```
open: function() {
  this.controller.set('isFirst', true);
  this.render('modal', { into: 'application', outlet: 'modal' });
},

openModal: function(arg) {
  this.controller.set('isFirst', false);
  this.render('modal', { into: 'application',     outlet: 'modal' });
},
```

Working jsbin here: http://jsbin.com/OTiRerA/1/